# How to Update fields value in embedded documents of an Array in MongoDB using Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I have the following structure in my document:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5891a85bccaad513a844308f"),
  "sites": [
    {
      "site": "site1",
      "url": "site1.com",
      "status": 1,
    },
    {
      "site": "site2",
      "url": "site2.com",
      "status": 1,
    },
    {
      "site": "site3",
      "url": "site3.com",
      "status": 1,
    }
  ]
}
```

then I load all sites to UI. then I'll do some changes like following image and hit Update. I have deleted "site3".
[image]
 then My structure should update like as follow. site3 status should update to 0

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5891a85bccaad513a844308f"),
  "sites": [
    {
      "site": "site1",
      "url": "site1.com",
      "status": 1,
    },
    {
      "site": "site2",
      "url": "site2.com",
      "status": 1,
    },
    {
      "site": "site3",
      "url": "site3.com",
      "status": 0,
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of positional [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) update.

The query filter finds the matching `site` in the array and update part will set the `status` to 0 to matching element.

```
collection.updateOne(new Document("_id", new ObjectId("5891a85bccaad513a844308f")).append("sites.site", "site3"), Updates.set("sites.$.status", 0));
```

Comment: but the problem is How to find what site was deleted from the list. Imagine site2 and site3 will delete, how to get that sites to update ?

Comment: I think you should keep track of it in the client code. It would be much simpler that way.